# Is there any way to disable wordpress website for desktop version only?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, web

Is there any way to disable website for desktop version only and it will be available for mobile version.

I have search on google but did not find the answer pleaes help me.

Comment: `@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) { * { display: none; } }` I suppose. That said, **why the hell?!**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is there any way to stop using jquery?

Comment: You can check the screen width in jQuery, I guess. This is a really dumb thing to do to your users, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `wp_is_mobile()`:

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'se26676900_die', 0 );
function se26676900_die()
{
    if( wp_is_mobile() )
        return;

    die( 'Sorry, mobile only' );
}
```

Comment: +1 I never knew that this exists :) Do you have experience using this function?

Comment: not really, but what I know is that it isn't bulletproof. Read the codex entry for more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile

Answer (score 2):

You can stop loading your whole site on desktop using [MobileDetect](http://mobiledetect.net/) .

> Mobile Detect is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices (including tablets). It uses the User-Agent string combined with specific HTTP headers to detect the mobile environment.

So to use it you need to check if it is NOT mobile or tablet and prevent the site for loading or redirect them to a custom page with a message that the site is not made for desktop usage.

Example

```
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( !$detect->isMobile() ) {
 // IT IS DESKTOP 
}
```